# Longtable twocolumn and onecolumn in same page

Tags: longtable, two-column

I am writing a twocolumn paper, however I need to add a longtable in my paper. and the final output should be like in the picture below.. I tried \onecolumn and \twocolumn trick but it forces pagebreak.

[image]

Comment: Try the `multicol` package